# VBA Excel Change value in the group of cells with Msgbox doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I am trying to change the values in my group of cells (merged cells) with the Msgbox. Unfortunately it doesn't work at all.

My code looks as follows:

```
Sub Nocivils()
ans = MsgBox("Do you want to remove the civils description?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

If ans = Yes Then

   Range("H24:Q32").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "N/A"
   Range("H24:Q32").Select
End If

End Sub
```

I tried previously:

```
Sub Nocivils()
ans = MsgBox("Do you want to remove the civils description?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

If ans = Yes Then

   Activesheet.Range("H24:Q32").Select
   Range("H24:Q32").Value = "N/A
End If

End Sub
```

And still no result,

Could anyone clarify what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks[image]

Comment: `Range("H24").Value = "N/A"`.

Comment: `ans = Yes`.... you don't have a variable saying yes. You got a return value of `6` if yes is clicked. I assume thats where you go wrong first (apart from merged cells being evil on it's own btw).

Comment: ^ You really need `Option Explicit` turned on by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from merged cells being evil, you first might want to change:

`If ans = Yes Then` into >> `If ans = vbYes Then`

Using `Option Explicit` on the top of your module would have helped catch this un-initialized undeclared variable. Next, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/9758194) post on how to avoid the use of `Select`. You can assign a value directly. Note that the top-left cell of a merged area holds your value which you can change directly using value assignment demonstrated by @BigBen (`Range("H24").Value = "N/A"`), but don't forget to be explicit about your worksheet at least!

Some documentation on [`MsgBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function) function from MS.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
If ans = Yes Then
```

with:

```
If ans = 6 Then
```

*(`Yes` is a variable that been neither **Dim**'ed nor initialized.)*